# hasNextLine() break with \n

Tags: java

I want to write a while-loop with (`hasNextLine()`) to run the code, and I hope that it can break when I input successive two new-line(with the button "Enter" of the keyboard).

Can I break the loop without any break condition like string.equals(quit) etc;

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int[] input_Num = new int [3000] ;
int i = 0 ;
while ( sc.hasNextLine() ){
    input_Num[i] = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println(input_Num[i]);
    System.out.println(sc.hasNextLine());
}
```

however, the `System.out.println(sc.hasNextLine());` will always return `true` to break the loop.

Comment: You'll have to keep an account of number of other characters before each new line. When that is zero, the iteration shall break.

Answer (score 0):

It will always turn true until end of file, and while it does the loop will *not* be broken.

But all you have to do is test for an empty line.

Answer (score -1):

This can do something along the lines of what you want.

Basically, if you want to read lines, you need to read lines. You can't use `hasNextLine` and then `nextInt`, they don't work well together.

```
Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
String line;
int empty = 0;
int input;
while(true)
{
  line=scn.nextLine().trim();
  if(line.equals(""))
  {
    ++empty;
    if(empty==2) break;
  }
  else
  {
    empty=0;
    input = Integer.parseInt(line);
    // ... do stuff with input
  }
}
```